# Dismiss automatically after 1 seconds but this is call in millisecond create flickering issue on view

Tags: ios, show-hide, quicksort

In Ios I have create quick scroller bar in Tableview like contact List in iphone .when click any character from quick scroller bar then tableview is working good but the problem is, show this character on one view with label (I means to say indicate to user which character is click) and after indicate this character automatic hide this view in 1 second .On this position my code is working good but the problem is if user scroller finger on quick scroller bar very fastly than this function call in milliseconds and indicate view flickering (show and hide) . I want to solution if user click very fastly (before 1 sec) than Indicate view not hide , Indicate view hide after 1 sec . I am trying this code , I have use nstimer and remove this time if this function call , but this working 4 to 5 time is good but very fastly scroller on quick scroller this is not working good, flickering view . Please give me Solution.

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
    {
        //NSLog(@"title=====%@",title);
        lbl_text_index.text = title;
        view_Text_index.hidden = false;
        timerforText = nil;
        [timerforText invalidate];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


           timerforText = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(hide_index_View) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
          });
        return index;


 }

       -(void)hide_index_View
    {
        view_Text_index.hidden = true;
    }
```

**I need if time is valid then timer is nill and again wait for 1 sec and view not hide but the problem is very fastly call this function this . And starting 10 to 15 tap this is not hide but after some time is hide in less then a minute , Timer is not going invalid and nil .Please give me any solution if you know . please share with me your valuable knowledge**

Comment: You have added a timer for 1 sec so there is no chance that it calls before 1 second.

Comment: This not looks a right way to show & hide view. You need to look for better solution. If you still want this logic to be work you can check for timer isValid property. Don't do anything if the timer is Valid.

Comment: @Vijay Masiwal 8 , I need if time is valid then timer is nill and again wait for 1 sec and view not hide but the problem is very fastly call this function this . And starting 10 to 15 tap this is not hide but after some time is hide in less then a minute , Timer is not going invalid and nil .Please give me any solution if you know . please share with me your valuable knowledge

Comment: Invalidate the timer timerforText first before making it nil. Interchange these two lines 
        timerforText = nil;
        [timerforText invalidate];

Comment: Yes i am invalid the timer because if view hide in 30 millisecond  and user again click on another text so i want to set time 1 sec and view not hide on 30 millisecond . View hide after 1 sec

Comment: set nil after invalidate the timer. In your code timer is nil before making it invalidate.

Comment: At least up vote my comment  :)